# Translation from Sybase date into Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sybase

I have a hard time translating the following Sybase statement to Oracle. No matter what I did, I got numerous error from Oracle. I have a hard time with the Where portion.
Can someone help me?

```
SELECT * FROM address  
WHERE convert(char(10), dateadd(dd,3,date_modified), 112)  >= convert(char(10),    
date_modified, 112)
```

Comment: What is the significance of the 112 in the `convert` calls?  What is the significance of the 3 in the `dateadd` call?  Given a sample input (maybe two columns, one of them `date_modified` and another one), what is the Sybase output?  Which functions have you actually tried in Oracle?  What did you get as an error, or as incorrect output?

Answer (score 1):

Are you checking to see whether the day three days on from date_modified is greater than or equal to the date modified?

```
where trunc(date_modified+3) > trunc(date_modified)
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the addresses that has date modified 3 days greater or equal to the date modified. In other words, if I have 100 records with date modified Jan 1 2013. If today 3 users did an update to their address, so their date modified will be April 3 2013. My above sql statement should only get me these 3 newly updated addresses.